# Prisma not accept function as transaction? Really this?

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

[image]

In the documentation there is an example using function, like I'm doing at the screenshot, but what the heck, I already lost 1 hour in this, please someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable this feature in your prisma schema as follow:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}
```

[In the documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#interactive-transactions-in-preview) mention it :)